# Can the @ServerTimestamp be set once in Firestore, and skipped on update

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to have both `createdAt` and `lastUpdatedAt` fields, both of which are supposed to be set by the server.

To be consistent, I thought I'd create a wrapper that would always set these supporting properties to all documents:

```
struct FIRDocument<T: Codable>: Codable {
   let data: T
   @ServerTimestamp var createdAt: Timestamp? = nil
   @ServerTimestamp var lastUpdatedAt: Timestamp? = nil
}
```

and to use it like so:

```
struct Message: Codable {
   content: String
}

let ref = firestore.collection("messages").document()

// later
let newDoc = FIRDocument(data: Message(content: "hello"))
ref.addDocument(from: newDoc) { ... }

// later yet
let updatedDoc = FIRDocument(data: Message(content: "goodbye"))
ref.setData(from: updatedDoc) { ... }
```

Obviously, the above code just updates both of the timestamps. Is there a way to update the `lastUpdatedAt` without resetting the `createdAt` field in my set-up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not directly possible on the server. While you can reject overwrites of `createdAt`, and can require the presence of `lastUpdatedAt`, in security rules, there is no way to *ignore* a value that was passed in a write instruction.

That means you have a case here where the data you want to write to a document depends on the existing data in that document, and you will need to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions).

Comment: I see. What's the suggested approach to have a field like `createdAt` in FireStore? Should it be set by a cloud function when a document is created instead and never sent from the client? (Ideally, I would like to avoid making a transaction on every update)

Comment: What you want requires a transaction. You can do it in Cloud Functions, but it'll likely still need a transaction there.

Comment: Not to over-pound on the issue - just want to make sure I didn't miss anything - with a cloud function, this would just need to be done once in the `onCreate` trigger, and just a single field could be updated, no?

Comment: Ah, if you mean a Firestore-triggered Cloud Function that is indeed an interesting option. If you trigger `onCreate` you would indeed not need a transaction as much. There's an off chance it'll get triggered multiple times, but we're talking about extensive system outages for that to be the case.